# How to get only specific tables to create models from database with Entity Framework Core in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using `Scaffold-DbContext` to create models from an existing database, but it auto pluralizes the table names and I don't want that. It also gets all the tables but I need only a couple of them.

Is there a way to disable pluralization and select only some specific tables with that command?

Comment: If code generati1on has already taken you to 90%, you might as well copy the couple of tables and their DB context mappings in a file and forget about the scaffold.

Comment: Have a look at EF Core Power Tools

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
Scaffold-DbContext "[connection string here from database properties]" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir "path where your context should be created" -Tables ["tablename1","tablename2"] -NoPluralize
```

You can read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell) documentation for more information but this should get the job done.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a look at the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell) - you'd see:

**Scaffold-DbContext**

**Parameters**

...

- `Tables <String[]>` - The tables to generate entity types for. If this parameter is omitted, all tables are included.

...

- `NoPluralize` - Don't use the pluralizer. Added in EF Core 5.0.

So yes - both of your requests can be handled with parameters to `Scaffold-DbContext` - just consult the docs!